# "To be or not to be": How to translate "to be"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

How would one translate the "to be" in "to be or not to be"? 
Is "Sein oder nicht sein?" correct? 
Does "dasein" have a meaning similar to the "to be"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shakespeare words

*To be or not to be.*

are usually translated into

> Sein oder Nichtsein.

That made-up noun *Nichtsein* is there for reasons of style. German speakers adore nouns. It would be as valid to write *nicht sein* and make the whole sentence a verb phrase as in English. The meaning is almost identical, but unique compound nouns as *Nichtsein* label abstract concepts better than verb phrases.

Same with the noun *das Dasein*. There is a nearly equivalent verb phrase *da sein* and you can play with the slightly different meaning:

> Das Dasein besteht aus mehr als da (zu) sein.

*Existence consists of more than being there.*

The *zu* is needed by grammar but you may want to leave it out for effect.